# Como se puede reiniciar el ID automaticamente cuando se vacia una tabla de SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

quiero que al borrar los elementos de una tabla, el contador vuelva a 1, y que sea automatico. Como seria? Lo estoy haciendo en la base de datos SQLite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite no tiene el `TRUNCATE TABLE` de la mayoría de motores de bases de datos, así que hay que recurrir a sus métodos propios.

```
delete from `TABLA`; 
update sqlite_sequence set seq=0 where name=`TABLA`;
```

SQLite realiza un seguimiento del ROWID más grande que una tabla esté utilizando y lo guarda en la tabla especial `SQLITE_SEQUENCE`. La tabla `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` se crea e inicializa automáticamente cada vez que se crea una tabla normal que contiene una columna `AUTOINCREMENT`. El contenido de esta tabla puede modificarse utilizando las instrucciones ordinarias `UPDATE`, `INSERT` y `DELETE`.